# .htaccess redirect if URL contains an email address

Tags: apache, email, .htaccess, redirect

I want to allow clean URLs in the form of **domain.com/me@msn.com** which should redirect to **domain.com/?profile=me@msn.com** (URL encoded or not).

What RewriteRule would achieve this? It should detect an email address in the URL to redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's painful to match mail addresses with regular expressions. The RFC-2822 compliant regex is two pages long.  Simply matching the `@` should, however, suffice in your scenario.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^((?<!results=).*@.*)$ ?profile=%1 [L]
```

Edit: make sure that manually navigating to `?profile=...` still works by asserting this case.

Comment: Thats as accurate as I need. Thanks!